# Block access to certain domains with document.referrer

Tags: javascript

I don't want to display some content if visitors are coming from domain1.com domain2.com or domain3.com

```
<script>
var refers = document.referrer;

if(refers!="domain1.com") {
// bye bye content will not be displayed if domain1.com is the refer
} else if (refers!="domain2.com"){
// bye bye content will not be displayed if domain2.com is the refer
} else if (refers!="domain3.com") {
// bye bye content will not be displayed if domain3.com is the refer
} 
else {
// All other domains referrers are allowed to see the content
}
</script>
```

This code don't work, the another problem is that document.referrer do not grab sub-domains or www. Must be exactly as requested domain1.com if it contains www will not be detected.

I am new on this... Please do not suggest any htaccess rewrite rule

Thanks

Comment: Don't trust referrer, some people disable or override it because of privacy. And note javascript isn't a good way to block the site, it runs client-side and not-allowed clients can just disable it.

Comment: hello, I've tried with php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322570/http-referer-not-working-on-javascript-src But all of my pages are written in .html format

Comment: PHP code is so easy to place inside HTML documents. Just rename the document to .php and place the php code in `<?php /*PHP here*/ ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Before I address your question, I have to state this:

*Using `document.referrer` is very bad choice to solve this problem.  Anyone with the smallest about of skill will be able to hit the `view source` button and see everything.  This will only the most basic of users.*

*`document.referrer` is horribly unreliable and there are many reasons why it will be blank, even when the user is visiting from another page on your site.*

**For learning purposes this is OK, but this is an unacceptable practice in any real-world application or program!**

That said....

```
function isReferrerGood() {

  function strEndsWith(str, suffix) {
    var reguex = new RegExp(suffix + '$');

    if (str.match(reguex) != null)
      return true;

    return false;
  }

  var i;
  var domain;
  var goodDomains = [
    "example.com",
    "example2.com"
  ];

  var ref = document.referrer;
  // For testing purposes, we'll set our own value
  // Note that this is a sub-domain of one of our good domains.
  ref = "abc.example.com";

  // Loop through the domains
  for (i = 0; i < goodDomains.length; i++) {
    domain = goodDomains[i];
    if (strEndsWith(ref, domain)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;

}
alert(isReferrerGood());
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I want to block bad domains only I don't want to list the good ones.

Comment: Then use `alert(!isReferrerGood());`